# How to show data in list except using String?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have used linear layout (shown below) for data that i want to show in list view. how can i acheive this ?by using following code,i am getting blank listview, don't know why!
below is listview items

[image: Listview Items]

this is the code i am using

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private Context context;
private ArrayList<Data> friendListData;

private class ViewHolder {
    public TextView name;
    public ImageView pro_image;

    public TextView comment;

}

public ListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Data> friendDataList) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    super();
    this.friendListData = friendDataList;
    this.context = context;

}

// @Override
public int getCount() {
    return friendListData.size();
}

// @Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

// @Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder = null;

    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (convertView == null) {

        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.conversation_item, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        holder.comment = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.comment);
        holder.pro_image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.avatarPic);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    Data data = (Data) getItem(position);

    holder.name.setText(data.getName());
    holder.comment.setText(data.getComment());
    holder.pro_image.setImageResource(data.getPro_image());

    return convertView;
}


public class Data {
String name;
String comment;
int pro_image;

     }
  }
```

and in MainActivity.java ,i am using adapter like this

```
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView);
    friendsDataList = new ArrayList<Data>();
    adapter = new ListAdapter(MainActivity.this, friendsDataList);

    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: What you have tried so far and what problem you are facing ?

Comment: i have used adapter but could not met the requirements

Comment: post ur code wat have u tried

Comment: @Nidhi-post your code for better answer..

Comment: i have posted the code in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check your arraylist size like...

```
Log.i("====SIZE=======","======>"+friendsDataList.size());  
adapter = new ListAdapter(MainActivity.this, friendsDataList);
```

Declare your Data in different class.

```
public class Data {
String name;
String comment;
int pro_image; 
     }
```

Add values in your ArrayList for testing purpose like..

```
Data data=new Data();
data.name="nidhi";
data.comment="Android developer";

friendDataList.add(data);

Data data=new Data();
data.name="Hardy";
data.comment="Android developer. Ready to help you.";

friendDataList.add(data);
```

Before this line :

```
adapter = new ListAdapter(MainActivity.this, friendsDataList);
```

Comment: this is incorrect. you don't have to add the items before you set the adapter , as long as you still work on the same iteration of the message queue. in fact, you could even add items on the next iteration of the message queue, if you also call notifyDatasetChanged() . I don't get how after all I've explained this is the correct answer. I even got downvoted.

Comment: @androiddeveloper where i specify that "add the items before you set the adapter " ? Actually she get's 0 for friendsDataList.size(). So she forgot to add records in a friendsDataList. And yes I am not downvoter for your answer.

Comment: @Hardy you've written "Add values in your ArrayList for testing purpose like.." and then "Before this line :" . the order doesn't matter. the important part is that in order to show some data, you will need to provide the data.

Comment: Yeh the important part is that in order to show some data, you will need to provide the data.

Answer (score 1):

watch "[**the world of listView**](http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/world-of-listview-android.html)" lecture by google.

in short, what you need to do is:

1. create a single layout xml that will be used as a template for each row. set an id for each view that its data needs to be changed according to the data.
2. extend [**BaseAdapter**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html) and implement [**getView()**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29) to show the item according to the position in the data, and [**getCount()**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getCount%28%29) to get the number of the rows. you can implement the [**getItem()**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItem%28int%29) in order to get the item from the data .

   remember to implement the getView() method in an efficient way, as shown in the lecture (use the convertView if it's not null, and also use ViewHolder "design pattern").
3. set a new instance of the class you've created to be the adapter of the listView.

that's it.

there are plenty of examples of how to do it on the internet, even in the API demos.

it's more important to understand what you are doing though.

Comment: hi. i am using the above code . but don't know where the error is. could you please help?

Comment: @Nidhi most of the code is ok. what i've found that is problematic is that for getItem() you return the position instead of the data itself. you should have returned friendListData.get(position) . you can also change the returned type to "Data" so that you won't need to cast it in the getView() method. just some extra tips: you never need to call super() . you never need to remove/comment the "@Override" annotation. you can set the inflater right in the constructor instead of in the getView() method. last tip:consider changing the class name or putting it in the same package as of the activity

Comment: another tip : if you wish to see the listview with the rows in the UI designer, you can add to its xml attribute in the listView tag : tools:listitem="@layout/your_listview_item_row" , or right click the listView in the UI designer and choose "preview list content" and choose the layout of the rows.

Comment: @Nidhi on this website, if you find an answer that you think that has solved your problem, you tick it as "answered". you do it by clicking on the "V" shape button on the left of the answer.

Comment: actually by mistake i have undone my vote. i voted it up before. but now i am not able to upvote it again.

Comment: @Nidhi i don't understand. there is a "V" button beneath the votes counter for each post. you just need to click on it.

Comment: ok got it.. its tick button. but my problem is not fully solved yet. i am still facing a problem in coding and don't get any way to get rid of it.

Comment: @Nidhi what is the problem? please explain more. maybe put the most updated code? it's hard to guess...

Answer (score 0):

Create custom adapter using BaseAdapter or SimpleAdapter and override the getView method. Design a xml file like the row you want to display and inflate it in getview method

For detailed tutorial using BaseAdapter [clickhere](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-baseadapter/)

Answer (score 0):

Set Adapter like:

```
      public class AdptrSchedules extends BaseAdapter {
private ArrayList<Model> aList;
private Activity activity;
private LayoutInflater layoutinflater;

public AdptrSchedules(ArrayList<Model> modelValues, Activity activity) {
    super();
    this.aList = modelValues;
    this.activity = activity;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    return aList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {

    return aList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {

    return position;
}

public void setPositionSelected(int position) {

    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    layoutinflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    Model model = aList.get(position);
    // ModelTemp employeeLocalDataModel = aListStudent.get(position);
    if (convertView == null || !(convertView.getTag() instanceof ViewHolder)) {
        convertView = layoutinflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_txt_name);

        holder.imgPhoto = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_serch_img_photo);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
        convertView.setTag(R.id.row_serch_txt_name, holder.txtName);

        convertView.setTag(R.id.row_serch_img_photo, holder.imgPhoto);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.txtArtistName.setText("" + model.getNAME());

    holder.txtDay.setText("" + scheduleDay);
    // holder.imgPhoto.setChecked(aListMalls.get(position).isSelected());

    return convertView;
}

class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtName;

    ImageView imgPhoto;
}

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

It Worked for me

Create list_layout.xml and pass it to listview adapter

```
    private static class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public ListViewAdapter(Context context) {

        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    }

    public int getCount() {
        return ListviewContent.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ListContent holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater
                    .inflate(R.layout.list_layout, null);

             holder = new ListContent();
            holder.text = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.TextView01);


            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {

            holder = (ListContent) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.text.setText(ListviewContent.get(position));


        return convertView;

    }

    static class ListContent {
        TextView text;



    }
}
```

Design layout as you want and finally set it to list view

```
    setListAdapter(new ListViewAdapter(this));
```

Answer (score 0):

u can right click the listView in the UI designer space and choose "preview list content" .now choose the layout content that u want to show in your listView. it will give u an idea how ur content will look in listView.

Answer (score -1):

To create a custom ListView Item you should extends an Adapter Class (i recomend you the BaseAdapter class) and in the method getView(...) instantiate your layout.

A good example, with the patter ViewHolder (This with ArrayAdapter)

http://www.jmanzano.es/blog/?p=166

An here other with BaseAdapter

http://qtcstation.com/2012/04/a-limitation-with-the-viewholder-pattern-on-listview-adapters/

Aclaration. The pattern ViewHolder make your listview smooth because the use of the method findViewById is very very very slow. With the viewholder you avoid using it, only in the correct moments